# как отсортировать из массива?

Tags: php

Всем вечер добрый. Нужен ваш совет профессионалы. У меня есть массив (это данные из LDAP), в котором есть одинаковые пользователи с именами (displayname), но у них разные email адреса. Как мне выбрать тех у которых в email есть yandex.ru  (на самом деле в AD попадается один и тот же пользователь как User и Contact. А мне надо выбрать именно контакт, так как у него в email адрес yandex.ru. Но это отступление...). Я полагаю речь идет о сортировке или даже группировке.

```
$entries[1]["displayname"][0]='Alex';
$entries[1]["email"][0]='123@mail.ru';

$entries[2]["displayname"][0]='Alex';
$entries2[2]["email"][0]='256@yandex.ru';

$entries[3]["displayname"][0]='Ann';
$entries[3]["email"][0]='789@mail.ru';

$entries[4]["displayname"][0]='Ann';
$entries[4]["email"][0]='555@yandex.ru';
```

Comment: `foreach($entries as $entry){if(strpos($entry["email"][0], "@yandex.ru") !== false) echo "YES";}`

Comment: круто. сейчас попробую реализовать, пока кто то ответ не дал :) спс.

Comment: У вас 2 массива? `$entries` и `$entries2`?

Comment: не, не, - массив один - entries, и конечно вместо первых элементов 1,2,3 в нем $i бегает

Comment: я за `array_filter($entries, function($v){ return stristr($v['email'][0], "@yandex.ru"); });`

Comment: Думаю самый оптимальный вариант, это пример от @teran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать, посмотреть если не яндекс удалить элемент. Ну конечно же можете и в другой массив вставить если яндекс (что бы начальный массив не испортит.).

```
$entries[0]["displayname"][0]='Alex';
$entries[0]["email"][0]='123@mail.ru';

$entries[1]["displayname"][0]='Alex';
$entries[1]["email"][0]='256@yandex.ru';

$entries[2]["displayname"][0]='Ann';
$entries[2]["email"][0]='789@mail.ru';

$entries[3]["displayname"][0]='Ann';
$entries[3]["email"][0] = '555@yandex.ru';
echo '<pre>';

for($i=0;$i<count($entries);$i++){
    if(strpos($entries[$i]["email"][0], 'yandex.ru') == false){
        unset($entries[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($entries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вы сможете просто пройтись в цикле и собрать новый:

```
$userByYandex = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($entries);$i++){
    $domain = explode('@',$entries[$i]["email"][0]);
    if($domain[1] == 'yandex.ru'){
        array_push($userByYandex,$entries[$i]["email"][0]);
    }
}

print_r($userByYandex);
```

Comment: можно и с помощью `strpos()`

Comment: Да конечно, @rjhdby привёл пример, поэтому этот для разнобразия )